# In sequelize, how to query the model associated with 'through'

Tags: associations, sequelize.js

I am very new to Sequelize and need help to create a method to query between two tables. 
I have given three models named "*user*", "*project*" and "*user_project*".

*user_project* stores the relationship between users and projects. It uses two foreign keys (user_id and project_id) from other tables.
In addition, *user_project* has a field named "role" to specify the role of the user in a project. I am trying to figure out a way to extract user roles based on user "email". Note than user email is stored in user table.

The associations between them are as follows:

```
  models.project.belongsToMany(models.user, {
    through: models.user_project,
    foreignKey: {
      name: 'projectId',
      field: 'project_id'
    }
  });

  models.user.belongsToMany(models.project, {
    through: models.user_project,
    foreignKey: {
      name: 'userId',
      field: 'user_id'
    }
  });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Know this is very late but hope it will someone else in future -

**Using raw query and then converting the roles string to array -**

```
User.findOne({
    where: {email},
    attributes: [
        'id', 'email',
        [Sequelize.literal("(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(roles) FROM user_project UP WHERE UP.user_id=user.id )"), "roles"],
    ]
}).then( (user) => {

    if(!user)
        return null;

    user = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user));

    if(!user.roles)
        user.roles = [];
    else
        user.roles = user.roles.split(",");

    return user;

});
```

**Getting roles without Using Raw -**

```
User.findOne({
        where: {email},
        attributes: [
            'id', 'email'
        ],
        include: [
            {
                model: Db.user_project,
                required: false,
                attributes: ["user_id", "roles"]
            }

    ]
}).then( (user) => {

    if(!user)
        return null;

    user = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user));

    if(!user.roles)
        user.roles = [];
    else
        user.roles = user.roles.map(r => r.roles);

    return user;

});
```